# How to restore or undelete PricebookEntry records

Tags: pricebookentry

Is it possible to undelete/restore a deleted PricebookEntry record? I am not referring to restoring a Price Book or Product record but hitting the delete button on an entry record itself, then immediatley trying to restore it. It's not in recycle bin or db when you query for IsDelete = TRUE.  I've searched everywhere and can't a definitive but I'm pretty sure, once you delete a PricebookEntry record, it gone for good (unless you have it backed up somehow). Anyone can confirm?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Once deleted, they're gone. You can confirm this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm).

> ## Supported Calls
>
> create(), delete(), describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve(), update(), upsert()

Objects that can be undeleted will have a supported call `undelete()`. For example, [Accounts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm):

> ## Supported Calls
>
> create(), delete(), describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), merge(), query(), retrieve(), search(), undelete(), update(), upsert()